# Bootstrap 3 collapse panel programmatically

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i've got a question.
Is there any way to collapse and switch back bootstrap panel programmatically.

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
                ...
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#to">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="to" class="panel-body collapse">....</div>
</div>
```

I need to collapse it or expand with some handler.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
                ...
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="btn-group">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="to" class="panel-body collapse">....</div>
</div>


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#to">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i> Click me
                </button>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/5EtB4a09la)

Comment: It's not my case. I need collapse or expand depends on other input value. For example if it's 1 - collapse, 0 - expand